# react, state change but not re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

there is a case that I confused.

I have an object redux state: { show: true, creative: {name: 'a', tags: [t1, t2, t3] } }. This object have been mapped to props throught "connect" function of "react-redux".

When I change the attribute "show" or "creative.name", it does trigger re-render. But if I append t0 to "creative.tags", it does not run re-render.

```
# reducer.js
# block code does not re-render ===========
state.creative.tags.push(t0)
return state
# end block code does not re-render =======
```

I have to work around by assigning a new variable.

```
# reducer.js
# block code does re-render ===========
let new_state = Object.assign({}, state);
new_state.creative.dsp_tags.push(action.payload);
return new_state
# end block code does re-render =======
```

Could you please let me know how reactJS recognize the changed state?

Comment: Reducers should never mutate state but rather return a new state object so what you are doing as your workaround is correct. See here for more info: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: Thanks, @djskinner. The answer is very helpful to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mutate the state directly, you should always create copy and return a new state.
The fact that you are pushing directly into tags is whats causing the problem.

Create a new array instead before returning the state object:

```
const newtags = [...state.creative.tags, action.payload];
let creative= Object.assign({}, state.creative, { tags: newtags } );
let new_state = Object.assign({}, state, { creative } );
```

Answer (score 1):

`Reducer` by definition must consist of a or collection of `Pure Functions`. Meaning the ones where `state` must remain `immutable`. You can make a copy of your `state` object by using spread operation like `...state` and then do the necessary operation.